# How do I create a project from scratch in GNOME Builder?

Tags: programming, gnome-builder

After installing and running GNOME Builder (3.18.1-2ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 16.04) for the first time I click <kbd>New</kbd> Button on the top-left. Then I'm offered to create it from a existing project located on disk (which I don't think I have) or to enter a Git URL.

[image: New Project with gnome-builder]

I've googled around as to how I'm meant to create a project from scratch but couldn't find anything.

How do I create a Builder project from scratch?

Comment: I get this with Builder 3.20.4 (Arch Linux): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkpu5.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6MKh.png. And it seems the git repository doesn't have to be a URL, just any directory where you have done `git init` will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**3.18 and below:**

The best way to do this would be to create a folder somewhere where you want your project to be (this will be the top level directory for your project), then open `gnome-builder`, press `New`, then choose the `From existing project on this computer` option, browse for the folder you just created, select it, and press the `Continue` button (please note that if you enter the folder you wish to select in the file chooser this will not work, so instead of navigating inside the folder, go to the folder on the level just above it (which contains the folder you want) and make sure that the folder you want to use is selected, then press `Continue`, don't just go into the folder which you want to use, that won't work).

So just to clarify, if I wanted to use the `BigFatPanda` folder here, instead of going into it I would go into the folder containing it, select it from the list so that it is highlighted and then press `Continue`:

[image: Select but don't go into folder]

After doing so you will see that `gnome-builder` opens that folder into its IDE view and allows the creation and editing of new files and folders within it.

---

**3.20 and above:**

Starting from gnome-builder version 3.20 the user can now press `New` and then choose the `From a project template` option which will take them through the steps of creating a new project, choosing its location, it's name and language.

---

Another method is to either download a project which has a `configure.ac` file using `git` or `apt-get source` into a location such as your home folder, or to simply create a new folder and then do the following:

```
touch /path/to/project/folder/configure.ac
```

For if a folder contains a `configure.ac` file within it, it will be shown and may be selected from the `Recent Projects` or `Other Projects` section on the `gnome-builder startup screen.

Comment: I've done: `mkdir gb_test; cd gb_test; git init; gnome-builder`I can't select the folder with the "existing project ..."-option as, I guess, there is no `configure.ac` file in it. I can't select it with as git source project, as I don't know how make a Git-URL from this. It doesn't show up in `recent projects` or `other projects`.

Comment: I was able to simply create an empty folder and select that as my already existing project, perhaps try that and then put all the git downloaded contents into that.

Comment: When I `touch configure.ac` in a empty folder I can select it to use it as a new project. For me it seems this doesn't work otherwise. I'm using versoin 3.18.1-2ubuntu1 btw. I wonder if your answer is using the same version. Please post your version.

Comment: @MadMike: That was the version I was using when I posted the answer, though now I am running version 3.20. How exactly did you try to select the new project? Because if you go into the actual folder that you want to select that doesn't work, you have to have it selected in the view and then press `Continue`, is that what you are doing as it may not seem the obvious option?

Comment: As soon as there is a configure.ac-file in the folder the folder will show up in the very first window without a need to click on the "New" button.

Comment: @MadMike: Ok, I have corrected that.

Comment: Ok. With 3.18, selecting a folder without entering it and selecting "Continue" works. Thanks for you patiance @Paranoid-Panda :)

Comment: @MadMike: Glad I could help you finally get it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Builder provides templates to build projects from scratch

https://builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/creating.html

Comment: The templates are **not** offered with the 3.18 build which is shipped from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories.

Comment: @MadMike your're right. Builder is under heavy development. Ubuntu 17.10 would help. As it is not LTS, you can too install flatpak https://launchpad.net/~alexlarsson/+archive/ubuntu/flatpak and run Builder stable or nigthly from it https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder (see buttons at bottom)

Comment: TWIMC: Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) installs Gnome Builder 3.18 so you CANNOT create a project from scratch on it.